# Device Chooser Offine

Tags: android, eclipse, device, offline

I'm trying to use Eclipse to write Android Apps. When I try to connect my Samsung Epic I get a message that shows it Offline. Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: did you enable USB debugging on your phone?

Answer (score 0):

Settings -> Applications-> Development -> USB debugging

Comment: What's the exact message that you see?

Answer (score 0):

Open command prompt and execute adb.exe file which is located in platform-tools folder. Then 
kill adb by issuing 'adb kill-server' command and start again start adb by 'adb start-server' at a command prompt. Disable and re-enable USB debugging on the phone. Reboot the phone. Change the USB mode from disk drive mode to charge only mode. I hope following these steps will help you.